# How to print parent working directory

Tags: command-line, grep, ls, echo

How can I list everything in the parent directory without having to cd there. Can this be done with `echo`?

In othere words instead of having to do this:

```
cd .. && ls | grep somefile && cd mydir
```

Can I use `echo` to simplify what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you looking for `ls ..` ?

Comment: Yes, seems so simple. Please make this is an answer

Comment: In my opinion,  `echo` is complicating your question. you just need to do as @ByteCommander suggested, the rest of your command is fine.

Comment: I agree with you @Redbob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply list the content of the parent directory, just use

```
ls ..
```

as `ls` accepts a path as argument and `..` represents the parent of your current working directory.